# Search action menu icon is not hiding

Tags: android, scrollview, toolbar, searchview

I have a MainActivity on which Fragment is placed. Fragment having SearchView (        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
) and MainActivity has a SearchView icon in Toolbar.
I want to hide/show the icon from Toolbar when Searchview of Fragment is Show/Hide (like Flipkart app). It is working properly when one of Hiding or Showing method is used, But when i use both of them then it gives error like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
```

My code snippets are..

**MainActivity**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)
{
    _menu = menu;
    final Menu m= menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menus, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) DrawerActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = null;
    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
    searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m.performIdentifierAction(searchItem.getItemId(), 0);
        }
    });

    searchItem.setVisible(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void show_search(){

    final MenuItem searchItem = _menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.setVisible(true);
//        invalidateOptionsMenu();  //if i use this it not show the icon.
}

public void hide_search() {
    final MenuItem sitem = _menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); // gives NullPointerException in this line.
    sitem.setVisible(false);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

**Fragment code :**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{

         scroll = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);

// Total Height of layout which contains searchview
    ViewTreeObserver vas = lin.getViewTreeObserver();
    vas.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams vlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) lin.getLayoutParams();
            search_size = lin.getMeasuredHeight() + vlp.topMargin;
            lin.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        }
    });
         scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {

            float y = scroll.getScrollY();

            DrawerActivity d = (DrawerActivity) getActivity();
            if (y >= search_size)
            {
                d.show_search();
            }
            else
            {
                d.hide_search();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, why do not you inflates other menu.xml the fragment?
For example .. in your fragment insert

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

private Menu mMenu;
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu);
    mMenu = menu;

    MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    final android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView =
            (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

I have helped

Comment: No , you just try he flipkart app i want only to hide/show the search icon in toolbar while scrolling.